# Grails 3.3.10: running integration tests Error creating bean with name 'com.cabolabs.security.UserController'

Tags: integration-testing, grails-3.3

I'm trying to create an integration test for a service and keep receiving a controller, that is totally disconnected from the service test, can't be created. Spending a day or so on everything that might cause the issue, and failing miserably, decided to create a project from scratch and start adding line by line.

So I did:

- grails create-app test
- grails create-domain-class com.cabolabs.security.User
- added username and password String fields
- grails generate-app com.cabolabs.security.User
- grails create-service com.cabolabs.cloud.BalanceUpdate
- grails create-integration-test com.cabolabs.cloud.BalanceUpdate
- grails test-app com.cabolabs.cloud.BalanceUpdate -integration

That runs OK, the test fails because of the default code, that is not important.

Then I started to add references to services in the UserController, and the BalanceUpdateService, like mailService from the mail plugin.

The test worked as before.

Then I added this line, which I have extensively used in many controllers of my original project:

```
def config = grailsApplication.config
```

With that line, the whole thing felt apart and got the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cabolabs.security.UserController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cabolabs.security.UserController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringMockTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SpringMockTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.spockframework.spring.AbstractSpringTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(AbstractSpringTestExecutionListener.java:23)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:269)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(SpringTestContextManager.java:54)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptSetupMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cabolabs.security.UserController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1152)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at grails.web.api.WebAttributes$Trait$Helper.currentRequestAttributes(WebAttributes.groovy:45)
    at grails.web.api.WebAttributes$Trait$Helper.getGrailsAttributes(WebAttributes.groovy:54)
    at grails.web.api.WebAttributes$Trait$Helper.getGrailsApplication(WebAttributes.groovy:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 36 more
```

My question is, how can I have the config injected to my controllers and make the integration tests work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a project from scratch and added line by line, it seems adding this to the controller, makes the test for the service fail (which are not connected in any way): def config = grailsApplication.config

Since I used that in many controllers, I tested changing it to Holders.config and that actually worked. I'll report this as a bug to Grails Core.